# Matlab equivalent function for python librosa. resample

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

I need to upsample my original data of 250Hz to 96000Hz.I did it in python using librosa.resample. But when I did it in matlab I am getting a fluctuated signal. I used resample command in Matlab. I tried with interp,upsample but didn't work. I need to get an exact replica of upsampled output that I got in python. Why I am getting a different output in matlab? What I have to do to get the exact output of python upsampling in MATLAB? Is there any function equivalent to librosa.resample in matlab?

Comment: How does your code look like in python? In MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import your signal to the systemIdentification toolbox, and use the resample function there. I have used that before and it works accurately.

Simply write systemIdentification to the Matlab console. Hope it helps, if not you might need to post some code.